# SetCursorPos not working over remote desktop (reading from WM_INPUT event)

Tags: windows, mouseevent, remote-desktop

When reading mouse position in `WM_INPUT` event, and the mouse cursor is hidden, it seems `SetCursorPos` does not work when the app is used through remote desktop.

The same exact code works fine when the app is not used through remote desktop. i.e. I can get infinite mouse movements in all directions just fine, since `SetCursorPos` properly moves the mouse cursor at center of screen when the app is accessed locally.

Is it a limitation (perhaps security related) of `SetCursorPos` when accessed from remote desktop? Or is there a work-around to this? Or perhaps it is because the mouse position values are absolute (`MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE` bit is set)?

All values I read from `WM_INPUT` are not affected whatever I set in `SetCursorPos`.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this behavior is related to the handling of SetCursorPos (and mouse events) in RDP or VM environemnts desribed in https://communities.vmware.com/thread/189519

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's worth including some of the detail from the link directly in your answer. it makes your answer quicker and easier to use and preserves the value should the link die or get changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a really old thread, but in the current world situation, it might be helpful.

To fix problems with RDP and mouse you need to open `Local Group Policy Editor` and go to:
`Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Remote Session Environment`.

In the `Remote Session Environment` you need to set `Use WDDM graphic display driver for Remote Desktop Connections` to `disable`.

Probably `Windows 10 Pro` is required, but I can't check it.
This change you need to make in the machine you want to connect to (host).
Restarting Windows is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse is hidden, the SetCursorPos interface will become invalid. You can use a transparent mouse style to replace the operation of hiding the mouse, and SetCursorPos will take effect. In RDP, if SetCursorPos (x, y) is called consecutively, and the x, y positions are not changed, RDP will be cached and will not be set. Therefore, shaking to set the mouse position can solve this problem, such as static int delta=0; int x = 500; int y = 500; while(1) { delta++; SetCursorPos(x+delta, y+delta); if(delta >= 1 ) delta = -1; }